# translating for loop to create variables into purrr in R

Tags: r, for-loop, purrr

I created a function that results in a dataframe with a new variable. The function takes on two argments: a dataframe and a character value. I want to iterate that over a vector of characters (usually about 100 elements long). I am currently using for(i in myvectorofchars). Is there a way to translate my for loop into a map function from purrr? Here is my (much simplified) code:

```
create_dummyvar <- function(mydata, code) {
    myvar <- paste0("prefix_", code)
    mydata[[myvar]] <- 0
    mydata[[myvar]][mydata$somevar %in% code] <-1
    mydata
}
for(i in allcodes) {  myfile <- create_dummyvar(myfile, i) }
```

Comment: `purrr::map_df(your_vector, create_dummyvar)`  with a minimal reproducible example is always easier

Comment: yeah, that worked once I made my function have only one parameter. (I tried map2_df but it tried to iterate over all variables in the dataframe and elements of myvector.) Thanks!